# How can i wait until the response is returned before returning in http request c#?

Tags: c#, httpclient

I want to wait for the response to be returned before returning the result:

```
     private static async Task<object> GetTestFuncAppAsync()
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {                
            string requestUrl = <myurl>
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);             
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                result = responseContent;                 
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

How can i wait until the responseContent is read before return result ?
What seems to be happening is the it calls client.GetAsync and the calls return result and there is garbage text in there .
How can i wait until the response is finished ?

Comment: you already got all the response content.

Comment: no cause it takes time to get the response . it goes and tries to get the data and the goes to the last line , return result and result doesnt have any valid data ... its too fast . I want to wait until it is complete

Comment: It doesnt seem to wait. I expect valid json , but it returns some random text

Comment: Call the api through postman or your browser, see if the content is different.

Comment: it is not i have tried postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there shouldn't be any problems since you're already using async. Maybe try returning `Task<string>` instead of `Task<object>`? Maybe it's serializing weirdly in translation.